# Arguments for and against having live websites as working copies under Subversion

Tags: apache, svn, ftp

Currently my team's development workflow is as follows:

**1: Repository -> Local Development (Working Copy) -> Commit when finished

2: Repository -> Testing Server (Working Copy) -> Testing by client etc

3: Repository -> Production Server (Working Copy)**

Ongoing updates are deployed using SVN update.

I wanted to find out weather people are for or against having live websites on the production server as working copies rather than using svn export. I restrict FTP access and only developers can run SVN update's via shell and have denied access to .svn folders in the apache conf.

Comment: Kind of suggests that you don't have any test cases in your repo, which is dumb for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like having some build process (using Apache ant, for example) to deploy the web site from a working copy. Even if it just makes a copy initially, it might later on filter some resources, generate files, minify Javascript, or whatever.

At the minimum, the working copy should be a working copy of a tag in SVN, and yu should switch to another tag when releasing a new version. This would at least prevent from doing updates from a development branch of from the trunk, which could be unstable.